# 3 consecutive elements in Prolog using concat

Tags: prolog

So I am working on this problem to have 3 X elements to be consecutive in a list and can only use concat.

Here is what I've attempted:

```
threeConsecutive(X, L):- concat(X, X, L2), concat(L2, X, L).
```

Is this correct?  If not, can you please explain what I'm doing wrong?  From how I see it, I'm concatenating 2 X elements and putting them in another free variable named L2 and then will concat that again with the element X.  Finally I store that inside the original list L.

Would greatly appreciate if someone could check this over as I'm really trying to grasp the concept of concat within Prolog.

Thank you!

Comment: Most important here is how `concat/3` is defined. Is it some variation of [`append/3`](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=append/3)?

Comment: Hi @Boris , yes the question is regarding append* sorry, I just used concat as that is normally what I'm used to seeing.

Comment: @false I misread the problem, so I was answering the wrong question, and didn't have time to fix it

Comment: @Boris: I would say that your answer is right, regardless of the accept mark. Only the teacher will tell :-). But ... in a list ... needs what you did

Comment: @false Well ok, there you go.

Comment: @user41580: which textbook is this problem from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this correct?

no, the first problem being that append/3 (for sake of discussion, let's say the undefined concat/3 *is* append/3) states a relation among 3 **lists**. So

> concatenating 2 X elements and putting them in another free variable named L2

should be

```
concat([X], [X], L2)
```

This could be better expressed with unification, as

```
[X,X] = L2
```

The same problem applies in

```
..., concat(L2, X, L).
```

should be concat(L2, X, L).

```
..., concat(L2, [X], L).
```

and then you can see that the whole code would reduce to

```
threeConsecutive(X, [X,X,X]).
```

So the second problem is apparent, but since @Boris answer has already shown the proper pattern required, I'll avoid to repeat it here.

Comment: What are you referring to when you say "the second problem is apparent"?  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, maybe my question is a bit vague.  The main question is to append X three times consecutively.  append(_, [X,Y,Z|_] , L) seems to only work for 3 consecutive elements that are different.  That's why I'm trying to use X multiple times...  Can you please explain what I need to do to append X three times consecutively and put it in a list?  Thank you.

Comment: 'the second problem' is that you're asked to locate a pattern **inside** a list, but your code - once corrected - would match the **entire** list. To repeat X three times, just 'declare' it `[X,X,X|_]` in pattern

Comment: Great answer, @CapelliC , I am playing around with it and I believe I have it figured out now.  I initially had written [X, X, X| _ ] but when I ran it via SWI Prolog, my answer would return false each time (because my list was incorrect - I was only supplying variables that were different).  I got it now though.  Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is use pattern matching:

```
?- append(_, [X,Y,Z|_], [a,b,c,d,e,f]).
X = a, Y = b, Z = c ;
X = b, Y = c, Z = d ;
X = c, Y = d, Z = e ;
X = d, Y = e, Z = f ;
false.
```

`append/3` does the backtracking for you.

If you want to have the three elements in a list of their own, you can use two calls to `append/3`:

```
append(_, Suffix, List), append([X,Y,Z], _, Suffix)
```

As how to make a list with three elements: just say `List = [X,Y,Z]`. To make a list of any length you could even use `length(List, Len)`, so for example `length(List, 3)`.

And, if you need the three variables to be the same (as in, *unify* them), then just use the same variable: `List = [X, X, X]`.

Comment: The question I'm looking at is asking with the parameters as stated in my question threeConsecutive(X, L) - is my solution correct or incorrect?  Hope you can reply, thanks again.

Comment: @user41580 Why don't you try your solution -- it should be obvious if it is correct or incorrect. This smells very strongly of homework so I don't want to give a complete answer. Anyway, I am adding some more detail to my answer.

Comment: Hi @Boris , this is not homework, but it is a question in my textbook that I'm trying to solve to improve.  I think I kind of understand what you're saying: append([X,Y,Z] , _, L) <- this seems like it would suffice.  X, Y, Z will always be consecutive no matter what element comes in the list.  Is my thinking correct? Thank you.

Comment: @user41580 No, that is wrong: `append([X,Y,Z], _, L)` means "L is a list, and X, Y, and Z are its **first three elements**." What you seem to be after is any consecutive three elements, which is `append(_, [X,Y,Z|_], L)`, as in the answer!